# SmartFusion 2 Pin Assignments using Libero

Tags: fpga, clock, pinout, microsemi-fpga, smartfusion

I am currently trying to find the schematic or pinout chart for a MicroSemi's SmartFusion 2. I have read all of their reference documents and release notes, but I can't find which pin is wired into the 50MHz clock.

I did find this chart, however it doesn't contain the pin for the clock.

Does anyone here regularly use the SmartFusion 2 and could attach the pinout diagram with the clock pin specified?

[image]

Comment: That is not the SmartFusion2 pinout. That's the pinout for one evaluation board which uses the SmartFusion 2. Clock doesn't need to be listed because it's already allocated on the PCB. What you are looking for with CLK and RESET is any pin in the datasheet connecting to a "chip global" net. (Not "quadrant global" which isn't global at all, but restricted to one quadrant, as I discovered. If you need to know this information for that specific PCB, look at its schematic.

Comment: There is an internal 50 MHz RC oscillator. Could this be the reason you can't find pins for external 50 MHz?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I see what you are saying, I think. I just got this board so all I am trying to do is blink an LED. Don't I need to specify my input signal as the 50MHz clock that is built into the board?

Comment: @Justme There is an internal 50MHz oscillator, but in my experience with other boards, I need to use the pin that is assigned to that oscillator as my input.

Comment: There should be some example projects or at least pin constraint files that came with the board. Use those as a starting point, it may be easier than trying to read the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Microchip (Microsemi) SmartFusion 2's user guide for clocking resources lists an internal 50Mhz RC oscillator that doesn't require any external components to be available for the FPGA fabric's use.

Please, check documents listed below for additional info

1. [SmartFusion2 Clocking resources user guide](http://www.microsemi.com/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=132012)
2. [SmartFusion2 Pin descriptions datasheet](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/130718-ds0115-smartfusion2-pin-descriptions-datasheet)